# How to copy files using TrueZip TPath?

Tags: java, truezip

As a follow-up to [Convert .tar.gz file to .zip using TrueZip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9266974/convert-tar-gz-file-to-zip-using-truezip) how does one copy the contents of one compressed file into another using TrueZip? When I invoke:

```
TPath sourceFile = new TPath("c:/foo.zip");
TPath targetFile = new TPath("c:/bar.jar");
Files.copy(sourceFile, targetFile, StandardCopyOption.COPY_ATTRIBUTES);
```

I get:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\foo.zip (expected FILE - is DIRECTORY)
    at de.schlichtherle.truezip.nio.file.TFileSystemProvider.copy(TFileSystemProvider.java:397)
    at de.schlichtherle.truezip.nio.file.TFileSystemProvider.copy(TFileSystemProvider.java:364)
    at java.nio.file.Files.copy(Files.java:1219)
```

The thing is, I know for a fact that `c:/foo.zip` is an existing file, not a directory.

1. Why am I getting this error?
2. How am I supposed to convert a ZIP file to a JAR file using TPaths?
3. Does TPath require unmounting like TFile does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question... Please note I figured this out by trial and error so I could be wrong on some of the points:

1. Archives are treated as directories. `Files.copy(archive, archive)` is essentially trying to copy one directory to another. `Files.copy(Path, Path)` is made for copying a single file, not for copying directories recursively.
2. Now that we know archives are treated as directories we simply copy files from one directory into another:

```
Files.walkFileTree(sourceFile, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>()
{
    @Override
    public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException
    {
        Files.copy(file, targetFile.resolve(sourceFile.relativize(file)), 
            StandardCopyOption.COPY_ATTRIBUTES);
        return super.visitFile(file, attrs);
    }
});
```

3. Yes, you can use: `targetFile.getFileSystem().sync(FsSyncOptions.UMOUNT);`